# How to submit a form through onSubmit event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a ReactJS form with an onSubmit function and a "Submit" input as below.

```
<Form id="addItem" method="post"
  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <Form.Group>
    <Form.Row>
      <Col xs={6}>
.
.
.
  </Form.Group>
  <Form.Control type="submit" id="addItemSubmit" name="add" value="Submit" />
```

The handleSubmit function is supposed to performs validations not covered by HTML5 validations and then submit the form to an API. The function handleSubmit is as follows

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let isValid = validateAddItemForm(this);
    if (isValid) {
      console.log(isValid);
      //const url = "/api/addItem/" + this.props.matchId;
      console.log("match offer url : " + props);
      const res = fetch(url, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
         id: 0,
        }) 
       })
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((responseJson) => {
         return null;
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
       });
    } else {
      console.log(isValid);
      return isValid;
    }
  }
```

Now I have two questions.
How to pass the props to handleSubmit? I need to pass some props from the current Component to fully generate the correct URL for the fetch request.
How do I pass Form fields in the "body" of the fetch request? Is the filled form available as an object for the handleSubmit funcion when the Submit button is clicked? Or do I need to gather the values of individual fields using document.getElementById(<field_id>).value and pass it in the body?

EDIT: I am currently accessing each form field using the document.getElementById inside the form validation function. That doesn't seem to be a good idea. That is why I want to access it as an object if possible.

Comment: I think react use `onClick` instead and prevent default submission.

Comment: Forma values should be either passed from props, or in states which would make them accessible everywhere in the component.

Comment: onSubmit also seems to work. The form is not submitted when a user clicks the Submit button and then the code goes through the form validation. However, if I have to use onClick, then that will go on the Submit button. The question still remains is how do I pass the props of the Component to form the url and how do I access the form fields?

Comment: Form fields value should be held in states of the same components or in states of parent component passing them  down to props.

Comment: Can you give an example on how to accomplish that?

Comment: I'm not on laptop, but mobile, a bit challenging. But some tutorials show how to manage form states with onChange event from input and get it on `handleNameChange(event) {}` with `event.target.value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have access to the props of the component everywhere on the component using "this.props.propName". You just have to remember that if you are using "this" keyword inside a component method you have to bind it (on constructor or whatever) or use an arrow function instead of class method.

You also have access to the form fields when using onSubmit through the form itself passed with the event object, you can use event.target.elements to get an array of the form controls (inputs, button, selects, etc.)

And lastly, if you want to submit the form, you can use the submit() method inside your handleSubmit with again the form you get from the event like so: event.target.submit(). But I can see you are using the fetch API, so it is like you are already submitting the form like that. You can try to set the url on the form tag as the action attribute and submit the form with the submit() if it passes your validation.

[More info on the submit() method on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp)

[More info on accessing form.elements on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_form_elements.asp)

[Binding functions to components - to use "this" keyword inside them](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance)

For example:

```
<Form id="addItem" method="post" action={`/api/addItem/${this.props.matchId}`} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <Form.Group>
    <Form.Row>
      <Col xs={6}>
.
.
.
  </Form.Group>
  <Form.Control type="submit" id="addItemSubmit" name="add" value="Submit" />
  
  
  
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Your validation logic here
    // You can use e.target.elements to access the array of the form controls
    if (isValid) {
      e.target.submit(); //submitting the form to the link in action
    } else {
      console.log('Errors on form');
    }
  }
```

On the other hand, as others already commented on your question, you can make your component as controlled component, which basically means that each form control will have a value on your state and you will have access to all the fields values in state.

[Controlled components from ReactJS Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Comment: Very good answer to the question. However @user1933205 , you should consider to use ajax call to POST request so that you can wait for the response without leaving the page. Submit a form will cause it to leave page and reload same page back or another page. You'll loose the bes React advantage which is to re-render the exact portion of the page that has been changed. By waiting for response, you can display success message, hide form and/or internally redirect with React Router, all this without leaving the page. Good work!